# Automatic change to the full version of the site when trying to put on a hat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mobile-web, winter-bash-2020

When you try to put on a hat on the mobile version, it goes to profiles and there is emptiness, so it would be nice if it would automatically change to the full version of the site.

Comment: The mobile version is deprecated anyway, better not use it at all.

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard Why is a deprecated version of SO used as the main version when visiting on mobile, though? Might be about time the responsive theme is made default instead

Comment: @Zoe because responsive isn't complete yet, e.g. no responsive profile pages and review pages. But mobile theme is much worse, so for "ordinary" site usage, responsive is much better. Worth a feature request to stop making it default for mobile devices, IMO.